# How do I generate a Stack Overflow reputation logo (not sure how to term it)?

Tags: discussion

I see many people have a rectangular picturebox in their about page which has a Stack Overflow logo along with their reputation points (I am not sure how to term it).

How can I generate one? And what is it called?

Comment: Are you looking for your [flair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/567435/rahul/flair)?

Comment: @Mysticial, yep exactly. So it's called *flair* ... LOL didn't knew it. Please post it as answer.

Comment: "Flair" is also explained in [episode 54 of the Stack Exchange podcast](http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode54-2009.05.20.mp3), 04 min 31 secs - 15 min 00 secs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for your [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567435/rahul/flair). You can get to it from the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab in your profile.

Comment: Thank You. But is including the pic really needed in answer. Text description itself is enough believe.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of one-line answers. So I needed something to pad it out.

Comment: Understood but for this question one line answer is enough and again I somehow don't like my profile getting publicized :)

Comment: Wait... Why would if you ask this question if you weren't trying to publicize it? :)

Comment: Nope that at all not the reason ... I wanted to have that flair to use it in my resume and was not able to figure out how to generate one and thus had no other way than asking the question. Now I know and so I don't really mind deleting the question. am really not in favor of publicity.